# Get time difference in years in android

Tags: java, android, date

Hello I'm able to get the seconds, minutes, hours and days, but when I try to get the years the problem comes up.

I'm using the following code:

```
        Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();                 
        long diff = date.getTimeInMillis() - startDate.getTimeInMillis();
        long seconds = diff / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;
        double years = date.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Let's say the start date is 07/25/1994 and the end date is 07/28/2015
the result that I get is (21.0) instead of the of 20.97 . I need to get the exact age in YEARS for the users so; can you help me guys out?. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use Joda Time at all? That would certainly make life simpler...

Comment: What makes you think you can get floating point numbers if you work with `long` and `int` literals?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` and `long`. When you want precise calculations of floating point numbers, always use `BigDecimal`. Floating point math is not reliable in java. Simple example is `System.out.println(2.00 - 1.10);` guess what, it doesnt print `.90`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your variables:

```
double years = (double) date.get(Calendar.YEAR) - (double) startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your question about elapsed time or about decimal number calculation?

If the first, you should know that decimal numbers for elapsed years is somewhat odd. If the second, you should change the title of your Question.

## Elapsed Time

For Android, you should be using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library rather than the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The old classes are notoriously troublesome.

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines string formats for various kinds of date-time values. For a span of time in terms of a count of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds, the format is [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where `P` defines the beginning and `T` separates the days portion from hours portion. The Question is about a span of `P21Y3D`, or 21 years and 3 days. The Joda-Time library uses this standard format for both parsing and generating such strings.

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate( 1994, 7, 25 ); //  07/25/1994
LocalDate stop = new LocalDate( 2015, 7, 28 );  //  07/28/2015
Period period = new Period( start, stop );

System.out.println("start: " + start + " to stop: " + stop + " is " + period  );
```

When run.

```
start: 1994-07-25 to stop: 2015-07-28 is P21Y3D
```

## Decimal Number Calculation

If you are just asking about the decimal numbers, then [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630932/642706) by Samrat Dutta is correct: Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you care about accuracy. Otherwise you are using primitives with floating-point calculations. [Floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) **trades off accuracy for speed** of execution. As a general rule, if in doubt about which to use for business problems, go with BigDecimal rather than floating-point.

What do you mean by "exact age in years"? Here's the number of years with up to 200 decimal places:

> 21.00752908966461327857631759069130732375085557837097878165639972621492128678986995208761122518822724161533196440793976728268309377138945927446954140999315537303216974674880219028062970568104038329911020

```
Integer days = Days.daysBetween( start, stop ).getDays( );
BigDecimal daysPerYear = new BigDecimal( 365.25 );  // Approximate.
int scale = 200;  // Number of fractional digits desired.
BigDecimal years = new BigDecimal( days ).divide( daysPerYear, scale, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN );  // Banker's rounding.

System.out.println( "days: " + days + " ÷ " + daysPerYear + " = " + years + " years." );
```

When run.

```
days: 7673 ÷ 365.25 = 21.00752908966461327857631759069130732375085557837097878165639972621492128678986995208761122518822724161533196440793976728268309377138945927446954140999315537303216974674880219028062970568104038329911020 years.
```

As I said, you may find `P21Y3D` makes more sense than this decimal number.

Comment: As for a library for Android I would take: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP